# How to not take HTML scripts and only SQL scripts from a specific URL

Tags: python, sqlite, http, encoding, python-requests

I am attempting to grab a bunch of SQL scripts sitting in a URL accessible via only a LAN, and then execute these SQL scripts with Python SQLite, but have realized that in that same request to grab the SQL, I also grab some HTML and this hinders my Python SQLite command from executing. Thus I cannot create the database.

Here is the snippet of source code that does the request:

```
import requests

builds_range = range(1300, 1351)
print 'Getting data from the following URLs:'
for build in builds_range:
  database_url = r'''http://192.168.1.253:8010/builders/Simulation/builds/{build_number}/steps/test%20trivial%20cases/logs/data'''.format(build_number = build)
  print database_url
  print requests.get(database_url).text
  import_db(db_script_url = database_url, submit_cur = db_cursor, 
            parameter_parser = lambda parameter : parameter_parser_final_iteration_with_constraint(parameter, None),
            build_number = build, extract_runtime = False)
```

And this is the snippet of code that actually does the execution of the SQL script to form the database:

```
import sqlite3

def import_db(db_script_url, submit_cur, parameter_parser, build_number, extract_runtime) :
  conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
  conn.executescript(requests.get(db_script_url).text)
  conn.commit()
```

Because of the fact that HTML gets in the way, you can see from my standard output with the help of `print requests.get(database_url).text` statement, that things look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head><title>Log File contents</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../../../../../default.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body class='log'>
<a href="data/text">(view as text)</a><br/>
<pre><span class="stdout">
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

create table highlevelsynthesis(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT,
    parameter TEXT,
    rtl_output TEXT
);
```

and further down the text in the URL, I also have problems with encoding in displaying the single quote characters:

```
INSERT INTO
logfile(name, parameter, stdout, stderr, test_file, synthesis_config_file, status)
VALUES (&#39;dfmul&#39;, &#39;[[&#34;scheduler_type&#34;, &#34;sdc&#34;], [&#34;max_chain_delay&#34;, 0.9]]&#39;, &#39;/nfs/home/hongbin.zheng/buildslaves/253/Simulation/build/shang-build/tools/shang/testsuite/benchmark/legup_chstone/dfmul/20141210-103616-710585/hls.stdout&#39;, &#39;/nfs/home/hongbin.zheng/buildslaves/253/Simulation/build/shang-build/tools/shang/testsuite/benchmark/legup_chstone/dfmul/20141210-103616-710585/hls.stderr&#39;, &#39;/nfs/home/hongbin.zheng/buildslaves/253/Simulation/build/shang-build/tools/shang/testsuite/benchmark/legup_chstone/dfmul.bc&#39;, &#39;/nfs/home/hongbin.zheng/buildslaves/253/Simulation/build/shang-build/tools/shang/testsuite/benchmark/legup_chstone/dfmul/20141210-103616-710585/test_config.lua&#39;, &#39;passed&#39;);
```

What should actually be in there in place of `&#39;` is `'`.

As a result of this HTML, when `conn.executescript(requests.get(db_script_url).text)`is executed, I get the following error: `OperationalError: near "<": syntax error`.

What really puzzles me is that whenever I repeat this with a URL like: `VIVADOJPEG500 = r'''http://192.168.1.253:8010/builders/LongTerm/builds/1261/steps/custom%20target/logs/data/text'''` that also contains a chunk of SQL, I totally do not have this issue. I initially thought it had something to do with the `r` in front of the string, but after testing my URL with it, I realized that adding an `r` does not solve the issue.

Could someone who knows what is going on please help me to overcome this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I have just realized that is the reason for my problem. I should have included  one more additional level to the link with `/text` and this would then enable me to extract purely text from that URL with no HTML and whatsover! That explains why the other URL I posted works.

But I later on realized that even if I didn't have this option, I could have used the [BeautifulSoup4 Module](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to remove the HTML.

Problem solved!!!